# Bibliography Printing without Numbers - TikzPoster

Tags: biblatex, tikzposter

When attempting to print references in a block, there are no reference numbers to link to the citations.

*main.tex*

```
\documentclass[25pt, portrait, margin=0in, innermargin=1in, colspace=1in, subcolspace=1in, blockverticalspace=1in]{tikzposter}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\title{\textbf{Title}}
\author{Person Name}
\institute{Institution Name}

\usetheme{Wave}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\block{Introduction}{       
    blah blab \cite{mycitation1}. blah blah blaaaaah \cite{mycitation2}. bleeeep blooooop \cite{mycitation3}
}

\block{References}{
    \printbibliography[heading=none]    
}

\end{document}
```

*references.bib*

```
@article{mycitation1,
    author = {some guy},
    title = {paper name 1},
    journaltitle = {some journal},
    date = {2013},
}

@article{mycitation2,
    author = {some guy2},
    title = {paper name 2},
    journaltitle = {some journal2},
    date = {2014},
}

@article{mycitation3,
    author = {some guy},
    title = {paper name 3},
    journaltitle = {some journal3},
    date = {2015},
}
```

Where I should see a bibliography like this:

*[1] My citation1. (2013).*

*[2] My citation2. (2014).*

*[3] My citation3. (2015).*

I only see a citation like this

*[1] My citation1. (2013).*

*My citation2. (2014).*

*My citation3. (2015).*

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: Added an example. Should do the trick.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After some gray hairs with TikZ, all boils down to this simple example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
    \cite{ctan,companion} \cite{aristotle:physics}
\begin{center}
    \printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

A list within a list. The behaviour can be resolved, though:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
    \cite{ctan,companion} \cite{aristotle:physics}
\begin{center}\mbox{}\vspace{-\baselineskip}
    \printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Why does it work? [David Carlisle tells us in our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21531350#21531350):

> because it you add `\tracingmacros=1` and then `ediff` the files (a useful emacs feature) you find it starts to go wrong at `\if@inlabel \@noparitemtrue`, i.e. the bibliography is being set at the point LaTeX has just seen `\item` but hasn't yet set that item. So things are held back to (e.g.) add a bullet point at the start of the next paragraph. The `\mbox{}` just gets that out of the way so the references start in the *second* paragraph of the center environment, not the first.

---

I am not quite sure about the benefits of this center-environment that is introduced by the class, i have dropped the teamm a note. Hopefully, an update is on CTAN soon.

In the meantime, i made a fork and removed the center environment. [Bitbucket Tikzposter Fork](https://bitbucket.org/JohannesBottcher/tikzposter/src)

Comment: The pull request provided by Johannes is now available in TikZposter.

Comment: As of today the `tikzposter` version on CTAN (https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzposter) dates back to 2014 and does not have the fix applied.

Comment: @Dirk On the offchance that you are involved in `tikzposter` development. If not, please ifgnore. Is there any chance that the updated version goes to CTAN any time soon? The issue came up again in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/450384/35864

Comment: I have to admit that I currently have no time to support this project and I didn't hear anything from the other developers.

Comment: @Johannes_B should I add you as a developer to the current project, than it is easier to maintain?

Comment: @Dirk No. I am not a TikZ user. I couldn't be of any help. We have a user called `marmot`, he is very very skilled with TikZ. Maybe he wants to help out?

Comment: @marmot Are you interested?

Comment: @Dirk Not sure if marmot will see this here. Users normally only get notifications in comments if they are in some way involved in the post. Try the chatroom: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends

Comment: @moewe Unfortunately, I didn't reach him in the chat. Any other possibilities to get in contact with him?

Comment: @Dirk Sorry, not that I know of. As far as I know marmot does hang out in the chat quite often, you just have to be there at the right time.

Comment: @Dirk https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46784152#46784152