# Missing Numbers in Bibliography using TikzPoster

Tags: biblatex, tikzposter

When printing references in a block only the first reference number is printed, whereas all subsequent citations are printed without their number. (MWE below)

This seems to be exactly the same problem as in the following question, which was resolved a few years ago:
[Bibliography Printing without Numbers - TikzPoster](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243665/bibliography-printing-without-numbers-tikzposter)

The problem at the time was traced back to a `center` environment somewhere in TikzPoster. I think the problematic environment was removed in later versions. Unfortunately, I don't know where to look this up myself. Does anyone know if they recently changed it back to include the `center` environment? Everything worked fine for me during another project earlier this year.

I would be very happy if someone could suggest a workaround to fix this. Or if it's only a problem for me, help me figure out where things go wrong.

The following MWE for me reproduces the error described above (using `backend=biber` and compiling with LuaLaTex)

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\block{Block 1}{
    Lorem ipsum \cite{ctan,companion} and \cite{aristotle:physics}
}

\block{References}{
    \printbibliography[heading=none]
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: There is still a `\begin{center}...\end{center}` in `tikzposter.cls`. Namely in `\AtBeginDocument` and `\AtEndDocument`, respectively. Removing the environment solved the problem in the MWE for me. But I could only find a way to do this by directly modifying the `.cls` file which is normally not recommended.

Comment: A short look at the other answer makes me think this is the exact same issue. Johannes fixed `tikzposter` and his pull request was merged and is available in https://bitbucket.org/surmann/tikzposter/, but a release with the fix never went to CTAN. CTAN still has an old version dating back to 2014.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointer to the relevant part in the `.cls` file and also for clarifying that the merge didn't make it to CTAN! I now installed the version available on [bitbucket.org/surmann/tikzposter](http://bitbucket.org/surmann/tikzposter) and everything works as expected.
I'm just a bit confused that I didn't have issues with this earlier.

Comment: If you did not use `\printbibliography` or a similar list-based command you would have been fine. Anyway, you may want to contact the `tikzposter` developers about this issue and ask them to upload a fixed version to CTAN.

Comment: So what do we do here? Do we close this as a duplicate, since as it turns out it still is the same issue three years later. Or do you want an answer?

Comment: Since this is in fact exactly the same problem and resolution as three years ago, I don't mind if this is closed as duplicate. However, your note that the fix isn't implemented in the version on CTAN was crucial to me, so maybe this is helpful for others as well? Since I'm new on here I'm happy to leave the decision to you. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I left a comment under the original answer to warn people. I guess it makes sense to close this question since the only answer would be: Look at the other question, the update is not on CTAN.