# Bibliography does not number entries, except for the first entry

Tags: biblatex, tikzposter

I am using `biblatex` in a `tikzposter`, compiling with Overleaf (which I think uses `pdflatex`).

Here's a minimal working example which shows the issue:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\setlength\bibitemsep{10pt}

\begin{document}

\block{test}{Here's a reference \cite{refa}. And here's another \cite{refb}.
}

\block{}{
        \printbibliography
        \printbibliography
    }

\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image: screenshot of wrongly-formatted bibliography]

The first call to `\printbibliography` prints the first reference as normal, but then omits numbers from the rest of the references. In the second call, the remaining citation numbers from the previous call are printed (if there are more than two references, the numbers will be printed as `[2] [3] [4]` etc., all on the same line), and then the bibliography is printed as normal. Note that `\setlength\bibitemsep{10pt}` also only affects the second call, so this may be a wider formatting issue.

I have found a strange solution to this problem, which I will post as an answer. However, I'm interested in if there's a 'proper' solution.

Is there some bib-related command, or argument to `biblatex`, that will allow the bibliography to format correctly?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/243665/35864

Comment: @moewe Thanks - somehow I missed both this and the other question that's linked in the comments of that question... That said, I've just given the `\mbox{}\vspace{-\baselineskip}` command a try, and it only seems to work if both it and the `\printbibliography` command are inside a `center` environment, which I'd like to avoid in this case. Nice to see the root cause though.

Answer (score 2):

## The strange 'improper' solution

Since I've made a few posters using `biblatex` and `tikzposter` where the 
bibliography has printed as normal, I discovered that using environments 
such as `itemize` and `center` in the poster causes the 
bibliography to print properly (provided one of those environments appears before the `\printbibliography` command).

As an example, adding another block containing an `itemize`:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\setlength\bibitemsep{10pt}

\begin{document}

\block{test}{Here's a reference \cite{refa}. And here's another \cite{refb}.
}

\block{new block}{                 <--- new block containing an itemize environment
    \begin{itemize}               
        \item A test item.        
    \end{itemize}                 
}                                 

\block{}{
        \printbibliography
        \printbibliography
    }

\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image: screenshot of correctly-formatted bibliography]

Now both calls to `\printbibliography` behave as expected.

I assume the way in which environments like `itemize` and `center` are handled causes some hidden behaviour which allows the bibliography to be printed correctly, but from the user side this is very strange! If anyone knows why this happens, it'd be great to have an explanation.